# Bluehost mod_rewrite not working (code attached)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I use Bluehost to host website for my client for two years, the website was running perfect before, until there's a billing issue that lead Bluehost to suspend my account. Anyway, the billing issue was solved and the server is back!

BUT, the website is down due to `mod_rewrite` is not working. I have contact Bluehost customer service staffs for 5 times, and their responses are the same “The .htaccess is enabled and this is a coding issue, you should contact your developer, we do not support for coding part.”

Even I explained that I am a developer and I am 100 percent for sure that is a server issue but still kicked out from the chat every time.

I have tested the code and I'm pretty sure it's correct. But I still need someone's help to let Bluehost staff know the code is correct.

There are only two files on server:

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

index.php

```
hello
```

no matter what I request
- example.com/foo
- example.com/bar

The webpage should display a `hello` instead of 404 page.

Is the code above correct?

Comment: I think it's time to move hosts. That should definitely serve the `hello`. I haven't read anything good about AIG (owners of BlueHost).

Comment: Try turning on rewrite logging so you can see what is going on inside the web server. Also, if this is a VPS, consider Dockerising your application so you don't have to fight with environment woes every time you need to set up a server.